# Converting pandas series timestamp to list of unique dates

Tags: python, list, pandas, datetime

I have a column in pandas dataframe in timestamp format and want to extract unique dates (no time) into a list. I tried following ways doesn't really work,

```
1. dates =  datetime.datetime(df['EventTime'].tolist()).date()
2. dates =  pd.to_datetime(df['EventTime']).date().tolist()
3. dates =  pd.to_datetime(df['EventTime']).tolist().date()
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime(df['EventTime']).dt.date.unique().tolist()`.

Comment: Thanks @Psidom that worked.

Comment: thank you @Psidom it is a really good and straightforward answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `dt` to access the date time object in a Series, try this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['EventTime']).dt.date.unique().tolist()
# [datetime.date(2014, 1, 1), datetime.date(2014, 1, 2)]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"EventTime": ["2014-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-01-02 10:12:00", "2014-01-02 09:12:00"]})
```